# toString() - method doesnt' choose right Array Index

Tags: java

My topic is a adventure game. The heroes have Superpowers, but if I want to print the superpowers from a superhero, it prints just the last index of my array, which I set it before.

My code: `

```
public void createdTeam() {
    Superhero krieger = new Superhero("Thylraz");
    Superpower[] kriegerPowers = { new Superpower("Schwertwirbel\n", " Thylraz wirbelt mit seinem Schwert."),
            new Superpower("Schildschlag\n", " Thylraz schlägt den Zombie mit dem Schwert."),
            new Superpower("Durchschlag\n", " Thylraz macht einen Durchschlag!") };
    krieger.setSuperpowers(kriegerPowers);
    krieger.setHeroRole("Krieger");
    team.add(0, krieger);
    Superhero archer = new Superhero("Artemis");
    Superpower[] archerPowers = {
            new Superpower("gezielter Schuss", " Artemis versucht einen gezielten Schuss zu treffen."),
            new Superpower("Pfeilregen", " Artemis lässt Pfeile über den Zombie regnen!"),
            new Superpower("Falkenschlag", " Artemis ruft nach ihrer Falke!") };
    archer.setSuperpowers(archerPowers);
    archer.setHeroRole("Bogenschützin");
    team.add(1, archer);
    Superhero berserk = new Superhero("Adukan");
    Superpower[] berserkPowers = {
            new Superpower(" Elektroschlag", " Adukan lädt seine Äxte mit Elektrizität auf und schlägt zu!"),
            new Superpower(" Blutrausch",
                    " Adukan geriet in Blutrausch! Er haut auf sein Gegner mit voller Aggro!"),
            new Superpower(" Blutiger Schlag", " Adukan versucht einen tödlichen Schlag zu treffen!") };
    berserk.setSuperpowers(berserkPowers);
    berserk.setHeroRole("Berserker");
    team.add(2, berserk);
}
```

and my print method:

```
public void printOneSuperhero() {
    System.out.println("\nVon welchem Superhelden möchtest du die Daten sehen?\n");
    int index = selectSuperhero();
    System.out.println("=====================================================================================");
    System.out.println("Heldenname\tHeldenrolle\tHP-Max\tHP\tEXP\tKampfbereit\tlebendig\tFähigkeiten");
    System.out.println("=====================================================================================");
    System.out.println(team.get(index).toString());
    startMenu();
}

public class Superpower {
private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private static String superpowerName;
private static String actionDescription;

public Superpower(String superpowerName, String actionDescription) {
    this.superpowerName = superpowerName;
    this.actionDescription = actionDescription;
}
public String toString() {
         return "Skill: " + superpowerName + "\n" + "Beschreibung: " + actionDescription + "\n";

}
```

}

Edit:

```
public int selectSuperhero() {
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < team.size();) {
    System.out.println("Position: " + (i++) + "" + team.get(index).print());
    index++;
}
index = scan.nextInt();
return index;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
private static String superpowerName;
private static String actionDescription;
```

to

```
private String superpowerName;
private String actionDescription;
```

(Remove the `static` keyword.)

The `static` keyword means "the same instance of the variable for *all* of the instances of this class". Thus if you change the value for one instance, it will change it for every objects of that class.

Comment: It works, but now If the player creates a new Superhero it just prints: "nullnullnull"

Comment: You might want to come up with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/) so we can make sure we know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: it works guys, thank you very much! :) I found my mistake, I forgot to set my skills with a setter!